# Footnote On Footnote

Tags: footnotes

I want to add a footnote to another footnote. Searched a lot here and there and tried lot's of stupid ideas. The closest i came up with, was

```
\footnote{some footnote text\footnote{secondary footnote text}}
```

This displays the secondary footnote properly, but "secondary footnote text" does not.

My doc shortened to the essential minimum:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%% some NEW COMMANDS
%...
\newcommand{\greek}{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\centering}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry{undottedtocline}{section}

\mainmatter

\begin{document}

%some parts, chapters and so on....

\footnote{some footnote text\footnote{secondary footnote text}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice effort for the MWE ;). For further questions you could shorten it even more. I am not sure you actually need `siunitx` or `microtype` to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I thought about this. But i am too new to LaTex to know whether theses packages would have an impact or not. Just wait some years and i will be able to post proper shortened questions. Sorry for the time beeing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `footnotemark` and `footnotetext` placing the text outside the actual note.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}


This\footnote{Note 1\footnotemark}\footnotetext{Text for note 2} And this\footnote{Note 3.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @uhelp: …but think thrice before doing such a thing as footnoting a footnote!

Comment: I thought about this over 40 years. I DO want footnote on footnotes. It is not an ordinary minor science paper. Thanks for your answer.